# Installing PyAudio in OpenSuse 42.1 Leap Linux error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, linux, gcc

I am using a OpenSuse linux 42.1 leap 64 bit operating system. I wanted to use PyAudio library and used 'pip install PyAudio' but i am not able to install it as the 'error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1' keeps coming up...

I tried the following commands too:

```
sudo zypper install python-pyaudio
sudo zypper install pyaudio
sudo zypper install python-PyAudio
sudo zypper install portaudio19-devel
sudo zypper install portaudio19-dev
sudo zypper install libjack-jack2-devel portaudio19-devel
sudo zypper install libjack-jack2-dev portaudio19-dev
```

but  following output i get...something similar to all the commands above..

```
'Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'pyaudio' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'pyaudio' found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.'
```

I have already installed python headers using

```
sudo zypper install python-devel
```

please can anyone help me out?

following is the pip install PyAudio output:

```
Collecting PyAudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: PyAudio
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for PyAudio ... error
  Complete output from command /home/jesus/Documents/anaconda3/envs/python3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-yblkkkko/PyAudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpn7wy6nilpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
  copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src
  gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/jesus/Documents/anaconda3/envs/python3/include/python3.5m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/_portaudiomodule.o
  src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:23: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
   #include "portaudio.h"
                     ^
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for PyAudio
  Running setup.py clean for PyAudio
Failed to build PyAudio
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
  Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
    Complete output from command /home/jesus/Documents/anaconda3/envs/python3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-yblkkkko/PyAudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-4gamezy0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
running build_ext
building '_portaudio' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src
gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/jesus/Documents/anaconda3/envs/python3/include/python3.5m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/_portaudiomodule.o
src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:23: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
 #include "portaudio.h"
                       ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/home/jesus/Documents/anaconda3/envs/python3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-yblkkkko/PyAudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-4gamezy0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-yblkkkko/PyAudio/
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt response..........................i have installed portaudio using **'sudo zypper install portaudio-devel' and then used pip install pyaudio** and it worked... Appreciate it alot...thank you.... :-)

Comment: You're welcome! One piece of advice: before going through the whole process of asking a question, do a search first, because there's a chance that someone already ran into the same issue :)